# Universal covering space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ minus a point.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

What do we know about the the covering space of $\mathbb{R}^n-\{p\}$? Is it homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$? If not, is there any topological invariants that allows us to distinguish between the two?

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{y\} \cong S^n \setminus \{p,q\} \cong S^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R} $$

i.e $S^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}$ is simply connected if $n>2$. Now just examine the cases where $n = 1,2$.

Comment: Thanks, but what happens when $n=2$?

Comment: Consider the parametrization $\phi(\theta,z) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, z)$ where $\phi: [0,2\pi] \times (-\infty,\infty) \to S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I thought about this too. The covering space should be $\mathbb{R}^2$. To get an actual covering map I think we just consider the parametrization $\phi(\theta,z) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, z)$ where $\phi: [0,2\pi] \times (-\infty,\infty) \to S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$.